# If we cannot create an instance of an interface in Java and arrays are nothing but Objects. Then, How is it possible to create Array of interface?

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I was going through a code, which really got me confused.

```
interface Interviewer{
    void conductInterview();
}

class Employees {
    String name;
}

class HRexecutive extends Employees implements Interviewer{
    String[] Specialization;

    public void conductInterview(){
        System.out.println("HR conduct interview");
    }
}

public class paractise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Interviewer interviewers [] = new Interviewer[1];
        interviewers [0] = new HRexecutive();
    }
}
```

The above code compiles successfully, But I am confused how is it possible to create an array of Interface "Interviewer" , If Array are treated as object in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface are nothing else than the assertion that an `Object` has certain methods / attributes. Furthermore, arrays do not store the objects themselves, but the references to objects. It is the same like having a variable of type `Interviewer` storing an instance of `HRexecutive`: `Interviewer i = new HRexecutive();`. The reference `i` resides within the stack memory (at least, if `i` is defined within a method) and holds a reference to the actual instance created via `new HRexecutive()`, which resides within the heap memory.

As mentioned in [EJP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638508/4216641): array-elements are initialized with `null` if their generic type is `instanceof Object`. Therefore, no constructor for an interface is called when an array of `Interviewer` is created.

Answer (score 3):

The array is an object. It contains references to objects of the interface type. Those references are initally null. There is no instance of the interface being created anywhere when you create the array.